# How do get kendo window's content inside form tag?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-mvc, kendo-window, kendo-ui-window

I have the following HTML where Address is shown using Kendo Window

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="firstName" class="form-control" />
    <input id="lastName" class="form-control" />

    <button id="btnOpenWindow" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Click Me To Edit Address</button>
    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
        .Name("mywindow")
        .Title("My Window")
        .Width(400)
        .Visible(false)
        .Modal(true)
        .Content("<input id=\"address\" class=\"form-control\">")
        .Draggable(false))

    <button id="btnSubmit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
</form>
<script src="~/js/test.js"></script>
```

**test.js file**

```
$("#btnOpenWindow").click(function () {
         $("#mywindow").getKendoWindow().open().center();
        
});
```

**ISSUE**
Even though kendo window is defined inside the `form` it always renders at the end of the page just before `body` tag, along with its content. So `address` does not render inside the `form`. So when user clicks  Save, the address information does not get submitted to server.

How do get kendo window's content render inside form?

Comment: You might try defining the address fields as hiddens within the form, then on window close event update those values.

Comment: I skipped kendo window and used bootstrap modal